# Checkbox for property in a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this loop inside of a beginform:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DogList.Count; i++)
 {
     <tbody>                                   
        <tr>                                  
           <td style="width: 15%">
               <img style="height: 50%;" src="IMAGE" />                                          
           </td>
           <td>
               <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Kennel</p>                                          
               <h3>@Model.DogList[i].Name</h3>
           </td>
           <td>
               @foreach (var skill in @Model.DogList[i].Accolades)
               {
                    @skill.Merit<br/>
               }
            </td>
            <td>                                          
                 //HERE I WANT A CHECKBOXFOR

            </td>                                    
         </tr>                              
     </tbody>
}
```

I cant seem to be able to figure out how to make a checkboxfor for my bool?
Tried:

```
@Html.EditorFor(o => @Model.DogList[i].JoinTeam)
```

and

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(o => @Model.DogList[i].JoinTeam)
```

But nothing gets rendered in the view. I must be missing something obvious?
Thanks!

Comment: nothing is rendered in the view or only the checkbox is missing?

Comment: Thank you, please see my answer to @ScottMacMasters comment

Answer (score 0):

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.property); 
where your property has to be set in your controller.

OR, you can try to hardcode a html checkbox, something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="JoinTeam" checked />
```

where checked can be set by a ternary if

```
(bool)?' checked':''
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but i dont really understand.
Tried adding:
<input type="checkbox" checked> 
But nothing showed up in my view.

Comment: Yes, i´ve been trying this but nthing gets rendered. But thank you!

Comment: If nothing is rendered then either some html is malformed or you have css hiding stuff.  Did you look at the generated html by using the view page source option in your browser?

Comment: Very interesting..when i use view page source i can see this:
<input name="DogList[0].JoinTeam" type="hidden" value="false">
So why is type hidden and how can i change it?
Used this helper:
@Html.CheckBoxFor(o => @Model.DogList[i].JoinTeam)

Comment: If your using `CheckBoxFor` it will render 2 inputs, a `<input type="checkbox" name="DogList[0].JoinTeam" ... >` and `<input type="hidden" name="DogList[0].JoinTeam" ... >`. Because unchecked checkboxes do not post back, the 2nd hidden input ensures a value is posted for use by the `DefaultModelBinder`